# range() function produces error 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

Tags: python, typeerror

My problem is the following line of code:

```
zreal_zimg_dfs = [pd.concat([zreal_dfs[i], zimg_dfs[i]], axis = 1) for i in range(len(filestrings))]
```

The filestrings variables are taken from a directory if they match a certain form. They are then sorted and collected as an array of strings with this code:

```
#Setting up die cast adress-string we use with glob
string = str(DATA_DIR.joinpath('Checkup_*_NMC_{nmc_nr}_*EIS000{EIS_nr}.csv'.format(nmc_nr = nmc_nr, EIS_nr = EIS_nr)))

#Grab all the strings in the folder that fit our die
filestrings = [name for name in glob.glob(string)]
filestrings.sort(key = natural_keys)
```

I'm going crazy beause this has worked before but now I get the error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I printed out statement wise and found the culprit was this

```
  print(range(len(filestrings)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

while

```
print(len(filestrings))
```

simply outputs `24`, no questions asked.

Please help. When things like this stop progress programming is at its worst.

Comment: Is it possible you've shadowed `range` or `len` by accident by assigning a string to a variable with either name?

Comment: Oh my god yes. Thank you so much. The batteries whose Impedance values I'm analyzing are cycled in a range between 20% and 90% state of charge and I used range as a variable for that range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible you've shadowed `range` or `len` by accident by assigning a string to a variable with either name? You should avoid using any of the [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as object names.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate shadowing a bit? If that is an official name.
What I understand from what you said is that variable definitions 'overshadow' original functions. I.e. a defined variable has priority over say class methods?

Comment: It's not a term specific to Python. [This explains it well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). How bad of a problem it can cause depends on the the scope the shadowing applies to (e.g. if you shadow `sum` in global scope and you have a function that calls `sum` called in any scope...)

Comment: Bro, i've been hitting my head for hours with this crap and your post saved me! I named a variable inside the loop 'range' and it was throwing me that error.. Thanks!!!